# Is Spring Security OAuth2 token with MD5 Hashing still secure?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, md5, sha256

In Spring Security OAuth2, functions like readToken, getToken are still using MD5 Hashing Algorithm. But this is only used to generate authentication_id, token_id instead of the access token itself. Is this considered as secure? What if override all those functions with SHA-256 algorithm, will that be better?